# Highcharts how to show the top line in a column chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have lines for all rows except the top row.
I need to show the top grid line (where $ 50B) like the other lines.

I can't understand what's wrong. Please help me to do this.

Look at the image below to know what I mean.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
window.revenueIncomeChart = new Highcharts.Chart('revenueIncomeChartBox', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: null
},
subtitle: {
    text: null
},
xAxis: {
    categories: chartData.categories,
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#BBBBBB',
            fontSize: '14px'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    className: 'axis-class',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '$ ' + this.value + $.trim(chartData.tooltipSuffix);
        },
        style: {
            color: '#BBBBBB',
            fontSize: '14px'
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: chartData.tooltipSuffix,
    valueDecimals: 2,
    shared: true,
    split: false
},
legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    floating: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#f2f2f2',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    shadow: false,
    itemStyle: {
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#797979',
        fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
series: chartData.series
});
```

I have lines for all rows except the top row.
I need to show the top grid line (where $ 50B) like the other lines.

I can't understand what's wrong. Please help me to do this.

Look at the image below to know what I mean.

Comment: Try adding [`endOnTick: true`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick) and playing with [`maxPadding`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.maxPadding) on the `yAxis` . I can't reproduce your result in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/zjxp57n6/), but `endOnTick` with `maxPadding` should help.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my question.I tried to use your parameters but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you make a live exampe, e.g. on jsfiddle?